# Clojure: How does clojure.java.io/resource load file?

Tags: clojure

Could clojure.java.io/resource load file from classpath but outside of the jar file? When I put file within jar file, it'd load file but when I put file outside jar but in classpath it'd not load file.

Example

Jar name: hello.jar 
          within jar there is file hello.txt

```
java -jar hello.jar
```

I saw no problem to read file hello.txt file using line bellow

```
(->
  "hello.txt"
  (clojure.java.io/resource)
  (clojure.java.io/file)
  (slurp))
```

But when I put hello.txt outside of the jar but in classpath, it fails to load file.

```
java -cp . -jar hello.jar
```

hello.txt file in same directory with hello.jar file.

Br,
Mamun

Answer (score 3):

You can't mix `-cp` and `-jar` cmdline arguments in that way. You can either do...

```
java -cp ".:hello.jar" com.foo.Class  # should use ; instead of : on Windows
```

or add a

```
Class-Path: /some/dir/with/hello /some/dir/with/hello/hello.jar
```

entry to the jar `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file that includes local directory.([details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html))

I would recommend you *don't* use . as the directory, since this will be prone to errors or maybe security issues if the jar file moves.